# Visualize weights of deep neural network in scikit-neuralnetwork

Tags: deep-learning, scikits, pylearn

I played with the [scikit-neuralnetwork](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork), which is backed by the pylearn2 library. The pylearn2 [has functions](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/library/scripts.html#module-pylearn2.scripts.show_weights) to visualize learned weights of the convolutional kernels. Can I somehow access the learned model inside the scikit wrapper and visualize the weights aswell?

I am new to python so going trough the source of scikit-nn did not really help me.

Thanks